# Boolean Expression Evaluation For ExNor Gate

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I know that an xnor expression can be broken up as follows:

```
X xnor Y = X'Y' + XY
```

But but I know that sume of the complement of the same combination (x+x') is 1 always therefore shouldn't xnor be always equal to 1?
I got confused in this question when I was trying to solve the following problem:

```
Z=X*Y where * denotes xnor. Evaluate Z*X.
```

My answer was 1, which according to the provided solution is incorrect the correct solution was given Y.
How? Thanks for the help.

Comment: X'Y' is not the complement of XY.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth ah! Now I know the snag, still how do I prove the expression?

Comment: +1 for a well-formatted question by a new member.

Comment: Just perform an algebraic substitution, expand out the terms, cancel as appropriate, and then you're done.